# Mutil Consumer means my server using multi thread?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am working on a simple project in Java.
I want to know that if I write this code, `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.setConcurrentConsumers(2)` then my program use multi thread?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is yes.
Assuming that you are configuring it inside `@Bean` annotated method that configures your listener.
According to Spring AMPQ docs it should look somehow similar to that:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is also max number of concurrent consumers set up which means that you will be using something between `min=3` and `max=10` consumers.
If you set only `.setConcurrentConsumers(3)` it will mean that you are using fixed number. No more, no less.

Recommended reads are:
[Listener Concurrency](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#listener-concurrency)
[Annotation driven async config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#async-annotation-driven-enable)